# winload.eif isn't letting advanced boot options load

Tags: windows-8, boot

Notes: I am running a toshiba satellite c855 and windows 8.1.  I also have backtrack 5 set to dual boot, and puppy linux on a nearby usb (just little notes so if I have to do anything from linux to repair)  my laptop did not come with a disk of any form (recovery/installation).

I can boot into windows 8 just fine.  No problem there.  The issue is if I try to use one of the advanced boot options (ie pressing F8 on pre-windows 8 devices, or pressing SHIFT-restart, then troubleshoot, advanced, command prompt and/or refresh (are the two options I tried)) Windows restarts like normal, when it reboots, under the "toshiba leading inovation" thing it says "preparing command prompt".  Then a light blue screen appears, and it tells me that the file C:\windows\system32\winload.eif is missing or corrupt.  It then gives me the options to retry (goes back to same screen), go to option (same result), enter setup (goes to bios), or choose a different operationg system (from there i select windows 8.1 and everything works out fine).  What is going on?  I checked the directory, and the file is there, so it is not missing.  Can I just download a new one?  is that a bad idea?

I found [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/windows-8-is-missing-winloadefi-and-wont-start-up/7cb36b31-e9ce-4309-a2f7-da5d2dce390a) that is somewhat similar, but nothing helps, as I don't have the disk.  I don't know if the code

```
Bootrec /fixmbr
Bootrec /fixboot
Bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

would do anything for me, but I know bootrec isn't an msdos command.  Is it illegal to download a windows 8 installation disk, or is it just illegal to install windows with it, but not to use the troubleshooter?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: On Win 8 admin command prompt type "bcdedit /enum all /v >c:\bcdedit.txt" and post bcdedit.txt or a link to it. (The ">" above as in Linux is for redirecting output to file.)

Comment: Don't know if it works, as I solved the problem myself.  It's called acidently deleting windows while installing Ubuntu.  (Before you call me stupid, it gave me the option to completely uninstall Ubuntu something... , NOT windows.  The other version of Ubuntu I had installed was backtrack.  It didn't tell me it would delete ALL current operating systems of mine.